# How to add a list of objects to another class that has a member that is a list of objects?

Tags: java

I've got a class, `Omega`, that has as a member a `List<Alpha>`.  If I then had a list of `Omega`s, how would I add a list of `Alpha`s to get `Omega`?

```
public class testClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <Omega> omegaA = new LinkedList<Omega>();
        List <Alpha> alphaA = new LinkedList<Alpha>();
        testMethod(alphaA);
    }
    
    public void testMethod(List<Omega> blue){
    
        for (int i = 0; i < blue.size(); i++){
            Alpha x = new Alpha();
            Alpha z = new Alpha();
            x.setBob(i);
            z.setBob(i);
        }
        
        //How to add x and z as a list to the first blue in the list?
        //If blue had 2 entries in the list, how to add them to the second item in list?
    }
    
    public class Omega{
        public int number;
        public List<Alpha> beta;
    }
    
    public class Alpha{
    
        public int bob;
    
        public int getBob() {
            return bob;
        }
        public void setBob(int x) {
            this.bob = bob;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your logic and provide expected and actual results.  Also, `testMethod` accepts list of `Omega` by signature, but it is invoked with an empty instance of `List<Alpha>`

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize the list in Omega:

```
public class Omega {
    public int number;
    public List<Alpha> beta = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

then to add `x` and `z` to each `Omega`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blue.size(); i++){
    Alpha x = new Alpha();
    Alpha z = new Alpha();
    x.setBob(i);
    z.setBob(i);
    blue.get(i).add(x);
    blue.get(i).add(z);
}
```